# Linker script undefined reference to PUTS

Tags: c, linker-errors, linker-scripts

I'm trying to learn linker script
Here are my files

caller.c

```
extern void hello();

void main()
{
    hello();

}
```

helloasm.c

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    void hello()
    {
        printf("\nHELLO\n\n");
    }
```

link.lds

```
    SECTIONS
    {
      . = 0x10000;
      .text : { *(.text) }
      . = 0x8000000;
      .data : { *(.data) }
      .bss : { *(.bss) }
    }
```

compile.sh

```
    cc -S helloasm.c   #generate assembly file
    cc -c helloasm.s   #generate object file
    cc -c caller.c       #generate object file

    ld -o hello -T link.lds helloasm.o caller.o
```

when i'm using

```
cc caller.c helloasm.c
```

i'm getting the output
HELLO

but when the sh file is called
i'm getting error
**

```
helloasm.o: In function `hello':
helloasm.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `puts'
```

**
can someone explain why puts function is undefined

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.23.2

gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)
```

Comment: For questions like this, you should include the version of gcc that you are using. Also, `printf` with no arguments and a trailing newline is often optimized by the compiler to `puts`.

Comment: Also, your names aren't quite lining up. `helloasm`, `caller`, `assem`, `c` - which is it?

Comment: Unrelated: Did you intend to declare `int hello()` and define `void hello()`. Not causing your issue obviously, but noted none-the-less. Related: run your `cc` compile *that works* with -v to see the linker steps you're missing. I'm  guessing you're leaving out something rather important (like libs).

Comment: correctly naming
even after changing it to void still getting undefined error

Comment: I'm not seeing where `libc` is linked in. Do you have your own implementation of `printf`?

Comment: no printf is default std library

Comment: Right. The C standard library, aka `libc`, often `glibc`. That stuff doesn't just appear in your executable magically. You need to include `libc` in your final link stage.

Comment: added 
ld -o hello -T link.lds helloasm.o -lglibc caller.o

ld: cannot find -lglibc

Comment: @JonathonReinhart whats the syntak to add glibc

Comment: `-lc` I believe. But why are you you going through all of this hassle? What are you trying to accomplish that you can't with just `gcc -o hello caller.c helloasm.c` ?

Comment: i know but the task is to  do it using linker script      
-lc still not working